# UDT error- pageCount is not a field defined in this UDT

Tags: spring, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I was trying to get the list of item from a product table from db on id search.there i have added a UDT column in product table.

```
try
{
  final List<Row> rows = session.execute(boundStatement.bind(pId, pmyTime)).all();
  if (!rows.isEmpty())
  {
    productDataList = ProductMapper.extractResult(rows, myBomObjMapper);
  }
}
```

in Init method -

```
    public void init(){

         session = cassandraSessionFactory.getSession();
         myObjMapper = new MappingManager(session).udtMapper(BomObject.class);
```

}

I was getting an exception

```
     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pageCount is not a field defined in this UDT
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: We need more information to be able to help you. What is your schema? How did you define that UDT? How does the mapper look like?

Answer (score 0):

> There i have added a UDT column in product table.

Did you add the column as an `ALTER TYPE` cql command after calling?:

```
myObjMapper = new MappingManager(session).udtMapper(BomObject.class);
```

If that is the case what is likely happening is that your `UDTMapper` has a stale reference to a `UserType` that represented the UDT at the time you constructed your mapper.   It doesn't look like the datastax driver will update this reference.   I see a jira ticket with a similar error message ([JAVA-1126](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1126)).   I'll comment on that ticket asking if this is something that should be supported.